# Netlogo: Using Levelspace extension with the extrawidget extension

Tags: netlogo

hope everyone is safe. Your assistance the question below would be very much appreciated.

I am currently using the Levelspace extension in conjunction with the extrawidget extension in Netlogo. Using Levelspace I'm attempting to have the parent model call a child model whose primary tab is an extrawidget GUI tab, which is tab 2. Levelspace always and only calls the interface tab which is tab 1.

Is there any way Levelspace can have the parent model call tab 2 instead of tab 1 when calling and loading a child model?

Thanks

Rudy

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "call tab 2", but if what you want to do is display a particular tab, that should be doable using [`xw:select-tab`](https://github.com/CRESS-Surrey/eXtraWidgets/wiki/Primitives#xwselect-tab). Is that not what you're looking for?

Comment: Hi Nicolas, thank you for responding. This is more of a Levelspace question. When I load my model that uses the extrawidget extension the extrawidget GUI is loaded and automatically displayed because, like you suggested, I use the xw:select-tab at startup. But when I use the Levelspace extension and I have a non-extrawidget first (parent) model call the extrawidget GUI model Levelspace will ignore xw:select-tab and always display the interface instead of the extrawidget GUI tab. Just wondering if there was anyway around this Levelspace restriction.

Comment: When you say that you "use the xw:select-tab at startup", do you mean in the `startup` procedure? I'm not sure that LevelSpace would run that automatically. You might have to call it explicitly from the parent model.

Comment: Yes, in the startup procedure.

Comment: Then something like `ls:ask ls:models [ startup ]` might help...

Comment: Hi Nicolas, your suggestion did not work. As an alternative I have separated the extrawidget model so that it stands alone (as a parent model in Levelspace) and calls a child model via a button on the extrawidget GUI. The issue now is I'm unable to pass the data, captured from the extrawidget fields, to the child model, specifically passing lists contained in the extrawidget model's global variable to the child models global variable. I've stored the lists in the extrawidgets global variable ("print" shows it in the command center) but I'm unable to pass it to the child model. Can you help?

Comment: I think that would warrant opening a separate question and posting the code that you use to try to pass variables around.